# Call include js script not from header, but on button clik?

Tags: javascript, html

I have  external scripts which I don't have control over, but need to use them a few times depending on which button is pressed. The system is thought to be used just once per page (it's a  chat script), so regular use is to just load it in the header.

Is there a way to dynamically load - unload said js scripts?

code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://chatservice.net/chat/script/29368.js"></script> //chat1
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://chatservice.net/chat/script/29378.js"></script>//chat2
```

Those scripts create divs and extra data (which unfortunately don't have a custom id or class to differentiate themselves).

Any idea on how to call them  / hide them after visitor closes chat? Visitor must be able to open / close any of the chats again.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can dynamically add a script tag:

```
const script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = 'https://chatservice.net/chat/script/29378.js';
```

Then append it to the head of your document:

```
document.head.appendChild(script);
```

You'll want to wait until it's loaded to do something, probably:

```
script.addEventListener('load', function() {
    // The script is loaded completely
    // Do something
});
```

Although this can probably work for you, there's probably a better method. It might be worth rethinking what you're doing here.